# Opendaylight - Why does Future work in init method but not inside rpc?

Tags: java, future, java.util.concurrent, opendaylight

I am developing an ODL application. This is an rpc in my yang.

```
rpc device-connection-establishment {
        input {
            list device-list {
                leaf device-id {
                    type string;
                    mandatory true;
                }
                leaf device-ip {
                    type inet:ip-address;
                    mandatory true;
                }
                leaf port {
                    type uint32;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

getSession is a function that I have written in Java, which will be used in the rpc.This function has a future object in it. doSomethingWith() is just a function where I am doing some operations on the arguments provided.

```
public void getSession(String deviceName, String ip, int port){
    Config config = doSomethingwith(deviceName,ip,port);
    io.netty.util.concurrent.Future<NetconfClientSession> clientFuture = netconfClientDispatcher.createClient(config);
    NetconfClientSession clientSession = clientFuture.get();
    System.out.println(clientSession);
}
```

I try to use the getSession function in the implementation of the rpc in the following way:

```
public java.util.concurrent.Future<RpcResult<DeviceConnectionEstablishmentOutput>> deviceConnectionEstablishment(
            DeviceConnectionEstablishmentInput input) {
                List<DeviceList> devices = input.getDeviceList();
                for (DeviceList device : devices) {
                    String deviceName = device.getDeviceId();
                    IpAddress ip = device.getDeviceIp();
                    long port = input.getPort();
                    getSession(deviceName, ip.getIpv4Address().getValue(), (int) port);
                 }
            return null;
        }
```

I also have an init function which is called from the blueprint automatically when the bundle starts.

```
public void init() {
        System.out.println("INIT STARTED");
        getSession("device1", "1.1.1.1", 2022);
    }
```

My problem is, the startNeConnect() inside init function works properly (ie) clientFuture.get() returns the result of the future. But the same function call inside the rpc does not work proerply. clientFuture.get() does not return anything and keeps blocking.

Why does this happen? I have even tried adding separate threads, timeouts. But it is not getting resolved.

UPDATE::: The two Future objects used in the above snippets are from different packages. The return type of the rpc is of type java.util.concurrent.Future. The future used in getSession is of type io.netty.util.concurrent.Future.

Comment: What is the type (class name) of the `Future` used?

Comment: The Future return type of the rpc is java.util.concurrent.Future. The one used in the getSession function is of type io.netty.util.concurrent.Future. I will update this in my question.